# Calculating Type 2 Error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, type-i-and-ii-errors

The question given is:

> When performing a test regarding the population mean, $\mu$, we decide not to reject $H_0$ when $\bar{X} > 3.$ It is known that $n = 50.$ If the true value for $\mu$ is $\mu = 3,$ what is (approx) probability of Type 2 error.

The answer to the question is 0.5.

My working goes as follows:
$H_0: \bar{X} = 3$, $H_1: \bar{X}> 3.$

By definition of Type 2 error, $$P(\textrm{Type 2 Error}) = 1 - P(\textrm{Reject}~ H_0 | H_1 ~\textrm{is true}) = 1 - P(H_1~\textrm{ is true}).$$

Then, $P(H_1~\textrm{ is true}) = P(\bar{X} > 3) = 1 - P(\bar{X} \le 3).$ Since the sample size is large, then by normalizing, $P(Z \le 0) = 0.5.$ Hence, $P(\textrm{Type 2 Error}) = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5.$

Is this the right way to derive the answer? Because I have doubts about the jump from $P(\textrm{Reject}~ H_0 | H_1~\textrm{is true}) = P(H_1~\textrm{ is true}).$

Appreciate any feedbacks.

Assumptions:
$n \ge 30$ is considered large.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What are the null and alternative hypotheses?

Comment: @Dave Hi! The question did not explicitly gives a null and alternative hypothesis. So, from the question (in the block text), I implied that the null hypothesis, $H_0$ be X bar = 3.